# How to disable dependency download in maven war plugin

Tags: maven

Is it possible to disable dependency download in war plugin other than using dependency pom type to provided?

I can't find the configuration for it in war plugin.

Comment: Just to see that I understand the question:
When you build using maven (mvn install ...), it automatically downloads all the dependency from the repository. You are asking how to disable it? meaning, make maven not download those dependencies? If that is the case, how would you like maven to get them? look in to a local repository? just fail?

Comment: I mean to not download jars into target/webapp.name/WEB-INF/lib directory when using war-plugin